# Display break tags in Jade Mixin

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, mixins

I have a JSON file that is being called inside of a Jade Mixin to display text. However, I need to insert a break tag in one of the JSON fields and don't know how to accomplish this inside the Jade Mixin. I can't seem to find the relevant information anywhere.

Here's the JSON file:

```
"features": {

    "employers": {
        "title": "For Employers", 
        "description": "Company corporate financial wellness program is designed to help employers lessen financial stress in the workplace, increase retirement readiness, and strengthen workplace culture.<br />Company offers a holistic approach to corporate financial wellness.",
        "featureList": [
            {
                "iconSlug": "puzzle",
                "title": "Easy Implementation",
                "description": "Company provides a robust, custom marketing and communication plan to help drive program awareness and engagement."
            },
            {
                "iconSlug": "rays",
                "title": "Ongoing Engagement",
                "description": "Get metrics around your employees’ engagement with the program and workplace impact."
            },
            {
                "iconSlug": "dollarSign",
                "title": "Affordable Pricing",
                "description": "Explore our pricing options for all company sizes, including low, per- employee rates that can be paid out of ERISA budgets."
            }
        ],
        "cta": {
            "title": "Contact our team",
            "class": "trigger-emailFormScroll"
        }
}
```

And Here is the Mixin that pulls it in:

```
mixin FeaturesModule(config)
h3.lvHeading.lvHeading-size3.lvHeading-main= config.title
h5.lvHeading.lvHeading-size5= config.description

- if (config.cta && typeof config.cta.newPage === "undefined") { config.cta.newPage = true; }

.layout-stdGrid
    each feature, i in config.featureList
        .stdGrid-col8.stdGrid-col-thin.padding-2
            abbr(class= "icon-mktgLight-" + feature.iconSlug)
            h6.lvHeading.lvHeading-size5.lvHeading-main!= feature.title
            span.block= feature.description

- if (config.featuredLink)
    a.link-featured.margin-Y-1.block(href= config.featuredLink.href, name=config.featuredLink.title, target= "_blank")= config.featuredLink.title
- else if (config.cta)
    - if (config.cta.href)
        a.button.button-wide(href= config.cta.href, target= (config.cta.newPage) ? "_blank" : undefined)= config.cta.title
    - else
        - var ctaClass = config.cta.class || "";
        button.button.button-wide(class= ctaClass)= config.cta.title
```

The span.block = feature.description is what I'm working with at the moment. What is the best way of making the mixin interpret the break tag so it's not printing on the page as text?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both solution will work:

```
span.block!=feature.description

span.block!{feature.description}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain a little more what that does?

Comment: Sure. Using "=" is HTML escaped. Using "!=" does not escape.
http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/

Comment: Please mark my answer as validate if it solves your issue